# Building DataGridView Display in Code (VB 2010 NET)

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview

I'm extracting information from an Excel Spreadsheet and trying to build the DataGridView in code.  I found [this information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8456826/at-least-one-of-the-datagridview-controls-columns-has-no-cell-template) very helpful.  In debug, everything appears to be right.  I have the right number of columns and rows properly formatted but nothing displays on the DataGridView.  Why?  This is really frustrating.

```
Dim dTable as New DataTable
For Each currcol As Excel.Range In inputRange.Columns
    dTable.Columns.Add(currcol.Value2, GetType(String))
Next

inputRange = objXLWs.Range("A" & HeaderRow + 1 & ":" & EndingColumn & EndingRow)
Dim i as Integer
For Each row As Excel.Range In inputRange.Rows
    Dim dataRow As DataRow = dTable.NewRow()
    i=0
    For Each incell As Excel.Range In row.Columns
        dataRow(i) = incell.Value2
        i += 1
    Next
    dTable.Rows.Add(dataRow)
Next

bs4DataPreview.DataSource = dTable         ' Set up BindingSource
dgv4PreviewData.AutoGenerateColumns = False
dgv4PreviewData.DataSource = bs4DataPreview
dgv4PreviewData.Show()
dgv4PreviewData.Refresh()
```

Edited source code to reflect use of DataTable.  Still getting nothing on DataGridView.

Comment: binding datagridview to an `iList`? try `DataTable` instead. although never tried it, your Of `String()` is an Array, which is not `iEnumerable`.

Comment: Is your inputRange correct? What does this `"A" & HeaderRow + 1 & ":" & EndingColumn & EndingRow` result in?

Comment: The data I'm interested in follows the header row which may not be row 1.  Likewise, the number of columns is variable.  I get the ending row from this beauty: Dim EndingRow As Integer = objXLWs.Cells.SpecialCells(Excel.XlCellType.xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

Comment: I agree with porkchop, use a DataTable as your DataSource instead.

Comment: Changed from using List(of String) to DataTable.  Same results!  Nothing displays in the DataGridView even though everything appears to be correct when viewed from Debug mode.

Comment: For the record, the problem was due to DataGridView.  I had to change several settings to get SelectionMode = FullColumnSelect to work.  That included flagging every columns SortMode to NotSortable before I could set the SelectionMode the way I wanted it. Strangely, I had to add a non-visible column to DGV before it would accept the new columns from the DataTable object.  It is now working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has been a long time since this question was originally posed. I continued working on the problem and  finally came up with a solution that is working.  It required building more intelligence into the DataTable.

```
Dim inputRange As Excel.Range
Dim i As Integer

BuildPreview = False
EndingColumn = ColumnIndexToColumnLetter(EndingColumnNo)
EndingRow = objXLWs.Cells.SpecialCells(Excel.XlCellType.xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

inputRange = objXLWs.Range("A" & HeaderRow & ":" & EndingColumn & HeaderRow)
i = 1
For Each currcol As Excel.Range In inputRange.Columns
    Dim column As New DataColumn

    column.DataType = GetType(String)
    column.ColumnName = "Column" & i.ToString
    column.Caption = NS(currcol.Value2)
    dTable.Columns.Add(column)
    i += 1
Next

inputRange = objXLWs.Range("A" & HeaderRow + 1 & ":" & EndingColumn & Math.Min(EndingRow, HeaderRow + previewRows))
For Each row As Excel.Range In inputRange.Rows
    Dim dataRow As DataRow = dTable.NewRow()
    i = 1
    For Each incell As Excel.Range In row.Columns
        dataRow("Column" & i.ToString) = NS(incell.Value2)
        i += 1
    Next
    dTable.Rows.Add(dataRow)
Next
```

I hope this proves to be helpful for someone else.