# using DataGridView(winForms) in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, xaml, datagridview

I am using datagridview (not datagrid) in my wpf application and i use this code to call it in my Window

```
<Window x:Class="TestHosting.MainWindow"
    xmlns:wf="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Forms;assembly=System.Windows.Forms"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="440.132" Width="521.053">
<Grid>

    <WindowsFormsHost Margin="20,20,130,142">
        <wf:DataGridView x:Name="dgv">

            <wf:DataGridView.Columns>
                <wf:DataGridViewColumn Name="column1" HeaderText="Col l" />
                <wf:DataGridViewColumn Name="column2" HeaderText="Col 2"/>
                <wf:DataGridViewColumn Name="column3" HeaderText="Col 3"/>
            </wf:DataGridView.Columns>

        </wf:DataGridView>
    </WindowsFormsHost>
```

and the problem is that an error says that "At Least on of the datagridview controls' columns has no cell template."

how should I fix this error ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8456826/at-least-one-of-the-datagridview-controls-columns-has-no-cell-template

Comment: forget winforms, it's totally useless. What do you want that for?

Comment: @HighCore why `winforms` is useless, can you explain please?

Comment: @Fabio because it's inferior, requires more code to achieve less, and whatever you want can be done in WPF just fine, without resorting to a bunch of ridiculous "owner draw" hacks.

Comment: @HighCore, sorry, I forget, we already discussed that before - I know your point of view :)

Comment: @Fabio Please, please show me ONE (1) thing that you can do in winforms that can't be done in WPF with 50% the amount of code and without resorting to stupid "owner draw" crap, oh and BTW, in a testable, platform agnostic manner that does not take a hard dependency on the UI framework so that you can reuse your code later in say, Android... Please.

Comment: You try to compare techniques which was created in different time, based on different understanding of programming. But why you so irritated by `Winforms`? Instead of talking about benefits of `WPF` you disparage another technique? About one thing: when I started work with `WPF` - was wonder, that changing vertical alignment in the cell style requires creating a new `ControlTemplate`. In Winforms's `DataGridView` same value can be changed by one row of code: `datagridview.DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleLeft`

Answer (score 3):

You could use **DataGrid**, instead of DataGridView

```
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from Table", con);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable("Call Reciept");
                da.Fill(dt);
                DataGrid dg = new DataGrid();
                dg.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
```

Comment: Except that DataGrid is very difficult to use in comparison

Comment: @rolls coming from WPF DGV is way harder