# Winforms: DataGridView: At least one of the DataGridView control's columns has no cell template

Tags: winforms, datagridview

I checked other questions on SO with this problem but they did not explain it.

`Add`ing the columns one by one works:

```
var columNames = ... //List<string>

foreach (var columnName in columNames)
{
    var column = new DataGridViewColumn()
    {
        Name = columnName,
        HeaderText = columnName,
        CellTemplate = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell(),
        AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells,
    };

    _dataGrid.Columns.Add(column);
}
```

when trying to create the columns first and then add them with `AddRange` fails:

```
var columns = columNames.Select(columnName => new DataGridViewColumn()
{
    Name = columnName,
    HeaderText = columnName,
    CellTemplate = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell(),
    AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells,
}).ToArray();

_dataGrid.Columns.AddRange(columns);
```

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'At least one of the DataGridView control's columns has no cell template.'
```

Comment: `var columns = columNames.Select(columnName => new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn() { ...`. Remove `CellTemplate = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell(),`.

Comment: PD: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8456826/at-least-one-of-the-datagridview-controls-columns-has-no-cell-template